# Managed Memory: Object count higher than expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-management, webforms, sqlcommand

I don't have much experience with the diagnostic tools within Visual Studio and it's something I'm using to further myself with the IDE.

In my application I've created my own class to help out with anything sql related, this class currently creates one SqlCommand and SqlConnection within a constructor , then it adds the SqlConnection to the SqlCommands.Connection and then stores both objects into their own properties. I'm persisting this class across post backs and when ever a page needs the command object I place

```
SqlHelper Instance;
```

At the top of the cs file, and then:

```
Page_Load:

if (Session["SQLH"] == null)
{
    Instance = new SqlHelper();
    Session["SQLH"] = Instance;
}
else
    Instance = (SqlHelper)Session["SQLH"];
```

then I simply do:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = Instance.cmd)
{
  // Do Stuff
}
```

(I don't want to hear anything like "blah blah garbage collection is very efficient, do this, do that")

Okay so now the **question**, when debugging my application I'm taking snapsots of the memory usage of my application and if I search for SqlCommand the count shows 8? If I search for SqlHelper (My class) the count shows 1, am I reading the results wrong or..?

I am using **using** statements, and I am closing my connections manually.

Snap Shot example:

Managed Memory:
   Object Type: SqlCommand
         Count: 8
          Size: xBytes
Inclusive Size: yBytes

If I select the objecttype it shows 7 reference counts of "DbCommandDefinition"?? and 1 count of SqlHelper.

Comment: If you destroy Instance.cmd using `using` then you can't reuse that object. So I wonder why your app runs at all. Besides that, you really shouldn't do this and create fresh objects for each request. Conn pooling makes this extremely cheap. This is just causing risk and has no benefits. It also prevents the use of running the app in multiple instances for HA.

Comment: The class isn't destroyed, it persists via a session variable so even with the using the object doesn't get destroyed. (I only added the using when I noticed the count in the memory) The whole purpose of this is experimenting different ways and finding out myself which way is more efficient.

Comment: Using disposes the object after which it is no longer functional. If this code runs then Instance.cmd must be a new object each time contrary to what you expect. Not sure what you mean by "destroyed", I meant disposed, which clearly is happening and is the *point* of using.

Comment: Removed the using statements, nothings changed and exactly the same outcome. SqlCommand count in memory is still 8(1 SqlHelper, 7 DbCD). Oh, sorry by destroyed I was referring to .Dispose();

Comment: Why is this a problem for you ? Is it just some thought experiment or is this code from some actual production application ?

Comment: It's genuinely just for testing purposes and for getting me used to this IDE and all the tools that it comes with.